# Standard align space with CD environment from amscd package

Tags: spacing, align, diagrams

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align}
foo &=\mydiagram{\text{width width}}       & bar &= \mydiagram{\text{width width width}}
\\[\jot]
foo &=\mydiagram{\text{width width width}} & bar &= \mydiagram{\text{width}}
\end{align}
```

where `\mydiagram{}` is a diagram composed with the `CD` environment from `amscd` package and it's defined as follows:

```
\def\mydiagram#1{%
    \begin{CD}
        S^{{\mathcal{W}}_\Lambda}\otimes T
        @>j>>
        T\\
        @V{#1}VV
        @VV{\End P}V\\
        (S\otimes T)/I
        @=
        (Z\otimes T)/J
    \end{CD}%
}
```

It follows my output:

[image]

I have used `align` environment because it calculates correct spaces between columns by himself, but not in this case. How can I fix spaces in order to have standard `align` environment behaviour?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}

\def\mydiagram#1{%
    \begin{CD}
        S^{{\mathcal{W}}_\Lambda}\otimes T
        @>j>>
        T\\
        @V{#1}VV
        @VV{\End P}V\\
        (S\otimes T)/I
        @=
        (Z\otimes T)/J
    \end{CD}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
foo &=\mydiagram{\text{width width}}       & bar &= \mydiagram{\text{width width width}}
\\[\jot]
foo &=\mydiagram{\text{width width width}} & bar &= \mydiagram{\text{width}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `tikz-cd` which does a much better job and has a simpler syntax.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! I have imaged that `tikz-cd` would have been better than `CD`, but unfortunately this choice it is not depend on me.

Answer (score 2):

Putting an `\fbox` around the `CD` environment reveals that the label sticks out the bounding box.  Therefore add space to your `\diagram` macro to accommodate the label

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{geometry}

\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}

\def\mydiagram#1{%
\hphantom{\scriptstyle #1}\mkern-28mu\begin{CD}
  S^{{\mathcal{W}}_\Lambda}\otimes T
  @>j>>
  T\\
  @V{#1}VV
  @VV{\End P}V\\
  (S\otimes T)/I
  @=
  (Z\otimes T)/J
\end{CD}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
foo &=\mydiagram{\text{width width}}       & bar &= \mydiagram{\text{width width width}}
\\[\jot]
foo &=\mydiagram{\text{width width width}} & bar &= \mydiagram{\text{width}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Of course the result is too wide for the page, so you should not put too many of these on one line.